# Did any children from non-magical families actually attend Cackle's?

Tags: the-worst-witch

At the end of the third season, Mildred convinces Ms. Cackle to open up her eponymous academy to students from non-magical families. According to what she said at the end of the season, she wanted admission to be open to girls who "have magic inside them even if you can't see it straightaway." The clear implication is that there are a number of students without any magical relatives who meet that criterion —and, presumably, that they will be able to learn *something* there, which is supported by several statements made by other characters over the course of the fourth season. In fact, when I first saw it I interpreted her as suggesting that students without any ability to do supernatural magic be allowed to study at Cackles.

Except, I only recall two students from non-magical backgrounds who attended the school that year. The first, Azura Moon

> who was the daughter of Indigo Moon after the later was sent back in time with a memory erasure.

Since I presume that such a spell could not have done anything to deprive her of her *ability* to do magic, Azura was from a witching family, being quite simply the daughter of a witch.

Similarly, we also have Izzy, who is descended from a magical family that lost their powers for a number of generations, as the result of an incident *rather* like the one that happened to Mildred's ancestor. As such,  she is also from a magical family.

Thus, both of these students were from magical families, and what is more, their unique circumstances hardly seem consistent with the sort of sweeping change Mildred mentioned near the end of the third season.  So, were there any students who attended the school in  Mildred's fourth year and did *not* have any witch or wizard relatives?